# Unable to get Request.Form data in API controller in .NET Core app when deployed

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Can someone help me with this issue?

While debugging the code on my local machine, it's working absolutely fine. When I deploy it to a server, it's not getting the form data.

Below are the lines of the code. I am really confused how come it's working locally, and it's not working on the server - am I missing any config or code?

My requirement: click on the tile OKTA tile and it directs to this below API controller.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("ValidateAccess")]
public RedirectResult getUserAccess()
{
    var strRedirectUrl = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build().GetSection("RedirectUrl")["CustomAdminUrl"];

    bool validateFlag = false;

    string strOKTAResponse = HttpContext.Request.Form["SAMLResponse"].ToString();

    if (SamlAuthenticateUser(strOKTAResponse))
    {
        // Check for Access
    }
    else
    {
        strRedirectUrl += "?flag=" + validateFlag + "&userid=OKTAFailed";
    }

    return Redirect(strRedirectUrl);
}
```

Comment: we need to see the code that calls this action. also it is possible it is not finding the strRedirectUrl because it cannot find the appsettings.json or something is failing.  this is not the way to use json settings anyways you are building the configuration everytime this action gets called which is not what you want.  you really want to load the configuration only once at the start of the application.

Comment: "RedirectUrl": {
    "CustomAdminUrl": "https://test.c3.bdstag.io/#/admin" }
Above is the redirect string from JSON. Problem here is strOKTAResponse is empty so it says OKTAFailed.

Comment: How do you know it is finding the configuration? are you debugging directly on the server?  You need to provide a fully reproducible example otherwise we cannot help you

Comment: Also if you are using net core... you might be better off using FromForm instead of Request.Form

Comment: I tried using FromForm still same issue. Do i need to change any setting in IIS Config..?

Comment: the real problem is your code is not complete. the rules for stackoverflow require a fully reproducible example